# is it possible to export a MobileNet model which has been retrained with the featureExtractor class in ml5js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

is it possible to export a MobileNet model which has been retrained with the featureExtractor class in ml5js?
It would be great to be able to import a retrained MobileNet classifier for project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. Your question is almost exactly the same as someone elses on Github, except their question was posted almost 3 months ago. See [here](https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-library/issues/174).

And the answer is also in that thread: It's not currently part of ml5js, but it will be implemented soon.